# How do I make my image stay centered where my div background colors split?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, web-deployment

html

```
<body>

    <header>

        <div class="indexHeaderWall" id="headerLeftWall">
        </div>

        <img id="profilePic" src="icons/myPicture.jpg" alt="Picture of Daniel Campos">

        <div class="indexHeaderWall" id="headerRightWall">
        </div>

    </header>

</body>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: 0%;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

#profilePic {
    position: absolute;
    left: 26%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto 0%;
}

.indexHeaderWall {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid red 1px;

}
#headerLeftWall {width: 30%;}
#headerRightWall {width: 70%;}
```

**I tried using percentages with position but I cant seem to keep my image horizontally centered on the split as I reduce my window size.**

**Left div takes up 30% of the width, while the right div takes the rest.**

**I'm assuming ill have to manually adjust position percentages to try and center a given image on the split, does anyone know of a method that would work on any given image? Or how I might adjust my current code to do so?**

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: What is the "split"? The vertical red line? If so, you need to calculate the width of the image and then use calc to subtract half of it from half the offset.

What is this exercise for?

Comment: Thank you for the help! Im currently building a website potfolio from scratch, this will end up being the top of my index page. I plan to combine a nav bar Ive built seperately with the header next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This keeps it in the centre.

```
<body>

<header>

    <div class="indexHeaderWall" id="headerLeftWall">
    </div>
    
          <img id="profilePic" src="icons/myPicture.jpg" alt="Picture of Daniel Campos">

    <div class="indexHeaderWall" id="headerRightWall">
    </div>

</header>
```

```
body {
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: 0%;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


#profilePic {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  right: 70%;
  transform: translateX( -50% );
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}

.indexHeaderWall {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
#headerLeftWall {width: 30%;}
#headerRightWall {width: 70%;}
```

[Example Pen](https://codepen.io/alexandra-drmt/pen/XWYqRar)

Comment: This is great, I'd rather do it this way than use JS to get the width of the image.

Comment: Thank you! I also prefer to use css only for such things :D

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

HTML

```
<div id= "container">
  <div id= "profilePic">
    <img />
  </div>
    <div id="colorLeft">
    </div>
    <div id="colorRight">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
 display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  heigth: 100%;
}

#profilePic {
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#colorLeft {
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

#colorRight {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 500px;
}
```

[Pen](https://codepen.io/mrdsantos/pen/xxzjgdL)

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you want to do it this way, but seeing as you're asking, you could use a combination of `calc()` and custom properties, get the image width using JS and pass the width value to the calculation, e.g.

```css
:root {
  --left-wall: 30%;
}

body {
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: 0%;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

#profilePic {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--left-wall) - var(--image-width)/2);
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto 0%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.indexHeaderWall {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid red 1px;

}
#headerLeftWall {width: var(--left-wall)}
#headerRightWall {width: 70%;}
```

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
img.style.setProperty('--image-width', `${img.width}px`);
```

Working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/morganfeeney/pen/MWXGJya) example